# how to fix a menu on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, header, fixed

Im modifiying a menu on my website here moroccoside.com and im trying to fix the menu once it reaches it with jquery

im using this jquery code on the header but it doesn't function

```
   <script>
   var stickyOffset = $('.header-wrapper').offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function(){
   var sticky = $('.header-wrapper'),
   scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
   else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
   });
   </script>
```

here is the fixed css class

```
   .fixed {position:fixed; z-index: 9999;}
```

**notice: i put the script in the header not from external js file**

any help will be so appretiated

Comment: Please define "it doesn't function". What you expect the code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: Might be an issue that the DOM isn't loaded yet. Try wrapping all that in a `$(document).ready(function(){ });` After that, if it doesn't work, check you console for errors, or try to debug that values that are being used.

Comment: Checkout this codepen: http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/dPpVbM

Comment: i expect it to fix the .header-wrapper class while scrolling down

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrapped in `document.ready` function. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var stickyOffset = $('.header-wrapper').offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function(){
     var sticky = $('.header-wrapper'),
     scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
     else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
   });
});
```

Comment: same doesn't function

Comment: You have error in last line. Please copy whole my code and paste in to your page.

Comment: it gives error "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function (index):91
(anonymous function)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure the DOM has loaded before this runs. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var stickyOffset = $('.header-wrapper').offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function(){
   var sticky = $('.header-wrapper'),
   scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
   else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
   });
)};
```

Comment: doesn't function yet, do i have to add it in a js file and call it then? or it should work even embed it on <header></header>

Comment: This should go at the bottom of your `<body>` before the closing tag, inside `<script>` tags.